# What to do when Mu'addhin makes mistake in Adhaan?

Tags: mistake, adhan

A month ago, I was invited to give Adhaan (Call to prayer) in Fajr in a mosque. Since I had done this only in a small mosque, I was a little nervous, but still did it. A few minutes after finishing, I realised that I had missed out the statement:

> ### الصلوة خير من النوم
>
> (Prayer is better than sleep)

Later, two persons pointed that to me, but none of them asked me to repeat the Adhaan. The remaining prayer went on peacefully.

Similarly, A Mu'addhin may also do mistakes like saying "ﺤﻲﻋﻠﻰﺍﻠﺼﻼﺓ" just once. After all, it is human to make mistakes.

Generally asking,

1. What does a Mu'addhin do when he makes a mistake?
2. If an Imaam makes a mistake in Salaah, [we  alert him by saying out loud "Subhanallah".](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5544/59) What do we do to point out mistake done by a Mu'addhin?

Answer (score 4):

**For forget the phrase "الصلاة خير من النوم" (Prayer is better than sleep):**

Must not repeat the adhan because the addition of this sentence is a sunnah and not duty, recompense who said it and no sin to those who left it.

**But for the makes a mistake in the adhan:**
Who left something from the words of the adhaan or iqaamah because of forgetfulness, if the time is slight, he should comes what forgets then completes adhaan after that, and else if time is long, it must repeat the adhaan or iqaamah from the beginning.

If he repeats the adhaan or iqaamah in both cases there is nothing wrong with it.

Al-Nawawi said:

> "لو ترك بعض كلماته [الأذان] أتى بالمتروك وما بعده ، ولو استأنف كان
>   أولى".
>
> "If he leave some words [adhan] came what he leave it and beyond, and
>   If he resumed was the best "
>
> [AlMajmo' (3/121)]

[Fatwa reference](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/131320)

Comment: Al-Nawawi's quote doesn't mention repetition. Will you please quote the statement that obligates it?